# Generically wrap member function of object to modify return type

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, std-variant, stdapply

Version restriction: C++17.

I'm trying to create a type capable of accepting a callable object of any type and wrapping one of its member functions (in this case, `operator()`) to take the same arguments, but modify (cast) the return type. An example follows:

```
template <typename Ret, typename Callable>
struct ReturnConverter : Callable
{
    ReturnConverter(Callable cb) : Callable(cb) { }

    Ret operator()(argsof(Callable::operator()) args)  // magic happens here
    {
        return static_cast<Ret>(Callable::operator()(std::forward<??>(args)); // how to forward?
    }
};

template <typename Ret, typename Callable>
auto make_converter(Callable cb)
{
    return ReturnConverter<Ret, Callable>(cb);
}

int main()
{
    auto callable = []() { return 1.0f; };
    auto converted = make_converter<int>(callable);

    auto x = converted(); // decltype(x) = int
}
```

`ReturnConverter` can take an object and override that object's `operator()` to cast whatever it returns to `Ret`.

The problem is expressing the argument types of the wrapping function - they should be exactly the same as those of `Callable::operator()`. Using a variadic template with `std::forward` does not satisfy this goal, as it would modify the signature of the function (`operator()` now becomes a template where it wasn't before).

How can I express the **`argsof`** operator I've highlighted above?

---

*Motivation*: I'd like to modify the `std::visit` overload technique demonstrated in [this article](https://www.cppstories.com/2018/09/visit-variants/) to be able to specify the desired return type from multiple lambda functors, so that I don't have to strictly match the return type in every lambda, for instance:

```
std::variant<int, float, void*> v = ...;
auto stringify = overload(
    [](int x) { return "int: " + std::to_string(x); },
    [](float x) { return "float: " + std::to_string(x); },
    [](auto v) { return "invalid type!"; }  // error! const char* != std::string
);
std::visit(stringify, v);
```

With the change above, I'd be able to write something like `auto stringify = overload<std::string>(...);`

Comment: Have you considered a variadic template?

Comment: @MatG I have, but this modifies the signature of `operator()` and so it's not a transparent wrapping (this is significant because it breaks `std::visit`, which attempts to call the templated `operator()` with the wrong variant type, resulting in a compilation error when the wrapper calls the original nontemplated function)

Comment: You can just [`std::visit<std::string>(stringify, v);`](https://godbolt.org/z/sTs8jWf39), C++20 already has overloads that can explicitly specify the return type.

Comment: @康桓瑋 Yep, that works for C++20. Sadly I'm limited to 17 in this question - I've now specified that in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a way to respond to your exact answer but... considering the "Motivation" of the question... I propose a wrapper for `overload` (a class that inherit from a class with one or more `operator()`, call the appropriate `operator()` from the base class and cast the return value to type `Ret`)

```
template <typename Ret, typename Wrpd>
struct wrp_overload : public Wrpd
{
  template <typename ... Args>
  Ret operator() (Args && ... as)
  { return Wrpd::operator()(std::forward<Args...>(as)...); }
};
```

and, given the `Ret` type isn't deducible from the argument (the `overload` class) and that CTAD doesn't permit to explicit a template argumend, seems to me that a `make_wrp_overload()` function is required

```
template <typename Ret, typename ... Cs>
auto make_wrp_overload (Cs && ... cs)
{ return wrp_overload<Ret, overload<Cs...>>{{std::forward<Cs>(cs)...}}; }
```

so your `std::visit()` call become

```
std::visit(make_wrp_overload<std::string>(
           [](int x) { return "int: " + std::to_string(x); },
           [](float x) { return "float: " + std::to_string(x); },
           [](auto v) { return "invalid type!"; } 
), package);
```

The following is a full compiling C++17 example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>

template <typename ... Ts>
struct overload : public Ts...
{ using Ts::operator()...; };

// not required anymore (also C++17)
//template <typename ... Ts> overload(Ts...) -> overload<Ts...>;

template <typename Ret, typename Wrpd>
struct wrp_overload : public Wrpd
{
  template <typename ... Args>
  Ret operator() (Args && ... as)
  { return Wrpd::operator()(std::forward<Args...>(as)...); }
};

template <typename Ret, typename ... Cs>
auto make_wrp_overload (Cs && ... cs)
{ return wrp_overload<Ret, overload<Cs...>>{{std::forward<Cs>(cs)...}}; }


int main() {
    std::variant<int, float, void*> package;

    std::visit(make_wrp_overload<std::string>(
               [](int x) { return "int: " + std::to_string(x); },
               [](float x) { return "float: " + std::to_string(x); },
               [](auto v) { return "(no more) invalid type"; } 
    ), package);
}
```

Comment: Indeed - initially I tried to write something close to this, but I didn't define the call operator properly, and so I mistakenly assumed variadic templates couldn't be used in this case. Your solution works perfectly, thanks.